# How to insert list of vector to a data frame

Tags: r, insert, data.table, row

I want to insert a list of vector (have the same element) into a dataframe.

**This is my code:**

```
library(data.table)
// create data frame and list
myFrame <- data.frame()
myList <- list()
indexRow <- 1
//to make a list of 100 vectors
for(i in 1:100)
{   
    myList[[indexRow]] <- c(i,i,i)
    indexRow <- indexRow + 1
}
// last is inset myList to myFrame
myFrame <- rbindlist(list(myFrame,myList))
```

I hope my frame would be

```
x1 x2 x3
1  1   1
2  2   2
3  3   3
...
100 100 100
```

But it is inserting by column, not by row:

```
x1 x2 ...  x100
1  2        100
1  2        100
1  2        100
```

*Can you help me?*

Comment: Why do you want to go about creating your data this way? It is likely to be slow.

Comment: Your data manipulations look a bit unnatural for R language. You can get the result with `myFrame <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:100, nrow = 100, ncol = 3))`

Comment: `//` is not the proper way to comment in R. Use `#` instead.

Comment: The `indexRow` in your `for` loop appears to be redundant, as it is equal to the value of `i` all the time.

Comment: Thank you , i has seen it !

Answer (score 0):

If you transpose your matrix, you should be fine:

```
t(myFrame)
```

As pointed out in the comments it is very inefficient to generate your data like this.